# Parse PHP serialized array in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have data written to an `html` file via `PHP` like so:

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));

if($data[0]!=''){
    $_SESSION['chatCode'] = $data[2];

    $fp = fopen('../sessions/chats/log_'.$data[2].'.html', 'a');

    $content = array(
        'author' => $data[1],
        'message' => $data[0],
        'time' => date('H:i:s'));

    fwrite($fp,serialize($content));
    fclose($fp);
}
```

However, I am struggling to parse the serialized data client-side in jQuery. My current code is this:

```
$.get('sessions/chats/log_'+chatCode+'.html', function(data){
    $('#chatContent').html(makePretty(data));
}

function makePretty(html){
    var data = JSON.stringify(html);

    console.log(data);

    var content = '';

    for(i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        content += '<div class="msgln">'+
            '<div class="meta">'+
                '<span class="name">'+data[i]['author']+'</span>'+
                '<span class="time">'+data[i]['time']+'</span>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="msg">'+data[i]['message']+'</div>'+
        '</div>';
    }

    return content;
}
```

The log file `log_test.html` contains:

`a:3:{s:6:"author";s:5:"e297f";s:7:"message";s:4:"test";s:4:"time";s:8:"09:23:23";}a:3:{s:6:"author";s:5:"e297f";s:7:"message";s:4:"test";s:4:"time";s:8:"09:26:39";}a:3:{s:6:"author";s:5:"e297f";s:7:"message";s:4:"test";s:4:"time";s:8:"09:37:03";}`

The console logs:

`"a:3:{s:6:\"author\";s:5:\"e297f\";s:7:\"message\";s:4:\"test\";s:4:\"time\";s:8:\"09:23:23\";}"`

Comment: It's quite odd to save arrays in a html document.

Comment: The client wanted the logs saved in a local file - it was either `html` or `txt` and I've saved logs to `html` in the past so it seemed the obvious choice. Having second thoughts now!

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you're `serialize($content)` data and writing it. Instead try `json_encode($content)` and write it. That should work with your current jQuery code.

Change

```
fwrite($fp,serialize($content));
```

To

```
fwrite($fp,json_encode($content));
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing serialized array is bad practice you mush use `json_encode` for saving data into file:

```
fwrite($fp,json_encode($content));
```

and while getting data in ajax, instead of using `JSON.stringify` use:

```
JSON.parse(dataString);
```